# After upgrading Wampserver program won't connect with database

Tags: php, wampserver

A program was created using Wampserver 2.4 (MySQL 5.6.12 & PHP 5.4.16) that accesses a database.

I attempted to run the program on another machine that has newly installed Wampserver 3.2.0 (MySQL 5.7.28 & PHP 7.3.12).The non-database components work fine but won't allow access to the db.

It falls over at the connect function where the following code is used:

`$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'votersroll');`

The 1049 error is given - unknown db 'votersroll'

Any ideas?

Comment: have you checked if the new server requires a password?

Comment: And you need to download your database from the previous server and export it to the new sever. and check for name changes.

Comment: Did you export and then import the db to your other machine?

Answer (score 1):

You need to export your database from the first machine and then import it to your second machine.

On your first machine:

1. Visit PHPMyAdmin : http://localhost/phpmyadmin
2. Select your database
3. Click Export tab and select the export method
4. Click "Go" and it will download an SQL file to your machine.

On your second machine:

1. Visit PHPMyAdmin : http://localhost/phpmyadmin
2. Create a database with the name "votersroll" and go inside the DB
3. Click Import tab and browse the file and select "Go"

Comment: It looks as though I didn't load phpmyadmin when I installed Wampserver as I can't get into it. Is directly copying the table in the db the same as exporting - there appears to be 3 files for the one table, .FRM, .MYD & .MYI?

Comment: What did you mean by directly copying?

Comment: Tried directly copying the table that constitutes the database but that doesn't appear to work. Copied 3 table files from C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\votersroll to equivalent folder on other machine.

Comment: Can you try importing it via PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: I have been able to create the database name 'votersroll' and then tried to import the 3 table files: voters.frm, voters.myd and voters.myi (the table is called 'voters'). This didn't work.